# SCM GIT export in Rundeck with remote SSH repository fails

Tags: ssh, version-control, export, rundeck

I try set up SCM GIT export in Rundeck, it fails on the stage of initial setup with the following error message:

> Failed cloning the repository from
>   ssh://user@gitserver/~/rundeckJobs.git: ssh://user@gitserver:22:
>   org.eclipse.jgit.transport.CredentialItem$YesNoType:The authenticity
>   of host 'user@gitserver' can't be established. RSA key fingerprint is
>   *******. Are you sure you want to continue connecting?

I understand that this is the message of SSH that is thrown upon first connect. I have tried switching to rundeck user and connecting to that server manually, in interactive mode, I have answered "yes" to this question, but the problem still stays.

Does Rundeck have it's own `known_hosts` file or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SCM configuration page for the project specify "No" for SSH: Strict Host Key Checking

Otherwise add it to the known_hosts file. The same SCM configuration page will show the path in the help section.